# Specifying pgf/tikz Inputs with a Different Language

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming

What I'd like to be able to do is say something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot+[only marks]
    coordinates {
      <Entirely Different Language>
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

where the `<Entirely Different Language>` could be in something like C, Python or Java. The idea is for this other code to print x and y values to stdout, and replace `<Entirely Different Language>` with these values, then proceed as usual.

Clearly, this isn't something that can be done "out of the box," but maybe someone has provided the infrastructure to make this possible.

If not, it wouldn't be difficult to write a latex preprocessor that parses out the `Entirely Different Language` stuff, feeds it to a compiler (if necessary), runs the code, takes the resulting output, and puts it into the original latex document at the relevant point.

If someone has already done this, then I don't want to reinvent an existing wheel.

Comment: `shell escape` is the keyword that lets you "do things out of the box". Once you can execute arbitrary code, the rest is trivial.

Comment: Yes, it seems like \immediate\write18, along with some macros, might work.

Comment: There was some Microcontroller emulator written in TeX by a crazy student (with which you could run C code, but I don't know the name anymore). Then there is obviously LuaTeX, in which "Entirely Different Language" could be Lua code.

Comment: Found something: https://gitlab.brokenpipe.de/stettberger/avremu/tree/master

Comment: That is hilarious, particularly that he claims not to be insane "that anybody knows of." I am tinkering with the \write18 idea now. I think it will work.

Comment: Depending on how you invoke the TeX run, you can also start other programs beforehand which write their output to a file you can then read in TeX (I usually use GNU make for this).

Comment: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109montijano.pdf has some examples for Lua.